# Use of session.use_cookies in php

Tags: php, session

I have searched around to find the impact on php session if I change the value of `session.use_cookies` to `true` or `false` but there seems to be no impact on how it works.

What is the use of `session.use_cookies` in php and why it is required?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: Do you know how sessions work? If not, please read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: @djot I gone though but information given here is not enough and clear about use_cookies.

Comment: It's not required, but advised to use it. Does make session hijacking harder. Add these two also, if possible: `ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); + ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);`

Comment: can you please explain here how session works if we disable cookies from browser and set use_cookies to 0 and use_trans_sid to 1. I got sessionid when echo SID but there is nothing found in url for session id and other session variables.

Comment: @PraveenD The most simple way to use sessions is adding a session ID value to the URL (in the query string portion). That is what would happen if you did not use cookies to transport the session identifier back and forth to the client. You use a cookie to kind of "hide" the session ID. You can still discover it, but it will not be in the URL and session hijacking will be harder. Thus, using a cookie for the session identifier amounts to a security via obscurity technique. HTTP is a stateless protocol. If an ID is not used to track specific clients, all session data must be sent as cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you want to manage your session id in client side, If set (default) the session id will be stored in cookies, otherwise it will be passed in url as a GET variable.

Comment: if you print_r($_GET); will you get session data ?

Comment: Please pardon me if you are confused with the above answer, If you use session.use_cookies you have to pass the PHPSESSID=1 in url like this,  http://localhost?PHPSESSID=1. The session id name depend on your php.ini configuration variable session.name = PHPSESSID. Pass the PHPSESSID in the url as get request, now you can access your session variable using $_SESSION['name']. Please let me know if I answered your query.

Answer (score 1):

Reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php will greatly answer most of your question.

Briefly, not using cookie will force you to ensure that for every action the user may do to change page, you have to pass the session id (otherwise, you will loose session context) : for web link, GET or POST form, ajax calls, etc. The session.use_trans_sid parameter may use, but it's not always sufficient.

Comment: I set session.use_cookies = 0 and restarted apache server. But there is no impact on session functionality.

Comment: If I disable cookies in browser session id can be accessed using echo SID, but print_r($_SESSION) returning empty array.

Comment: Browser sending no cookie means php can't associate the session datas and $_SESSION is empty. If the browser send the cookie, php gets the cookie whose name is SID, takes the value of this cookie and with this values, is able to retrieve the session datas and put them in $_SESSION. If no cookie, php have to get SID value by another way (GET or POST).

Comment: I set session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] =  'praveen@gmail.com';
$_SESSION['name'] =  'praveen'; If browser cookie is disabled, how will I access name and email on next page. can you explain with example.

Comment: Please read the documentation at the url I gave above. It will answer most of this question (tips : it's all about using the SESSID in url).